# How to remove/change font formatting for string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, fonts

how can I remove font type from string which is in database and saved with ckeditor?
For example:

```
<div style="font-family: Tahoma; color: Red;">
Foo FOooooo
</div>
```

I want to remove it or change it to Verdana for example.

I know I can use replace but font names can be different and I know I can use substring method. But is there any easy way to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple way by this `regex`:

capture `font-family` and `color` styles:

```
<div\s+style=\".*?font-family:(?<fontName>\s*[^;\"]*)?.*?color:(?<color>\s*[^;\"]*)?
```

and your code for replacement:

```
String inputStr = "<div style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: Red;\">";

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(inputStr, "<div\\s+style=\\\".*?font-family:(?<fontName>\\s*[^;\\\"]*)?.*?color:(?<color>\\s*[^;\\\"]*)?"))
{
    inputStr = inputStr.Replace(m.Groups["fontName"].Value, "Vernada").Replace(m.Groups["color"].Value, "Blue");
}
```

explain:

> ***`(?<name> subexpression)`***
>
> Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, the easy way, just remove the full div style using a "simple" Regex

```
 private static Regex oClearHtmlScript = new Regex(@"<(.|\n)*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

 public static string StripHTML(string sHtmlKeimeo)
 {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sHtmlKeimeo))
         return string.Empty;   

     return oClearHtmlScript.Replace(sHtmlKeimeo, string.Empty);
 }
```

and the hard way, use the Html Agility Pack (or any other similar) to parse the html and direct change the attributes.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks but if I use this method I clear/remove all html tags. I don't want it, just font-family that I want.

Comment: @kad1r then go with the Agility Pack, the second option.